# What arguments are needed for c# web method accepting an ajax post data with a file

Tags: c#, ajax, webmethod

I am trying to write a web method in c# to handle a post from a third party call. Looking at the post data I see that the call is posting:

> -----------------------------175734167351 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="blobid0.png" Content-Type: image/png
>
> PNG--------

What do I take as the input argument to process this call on the backend. I have tried

```
[WebMethod]
public void Save(string file)

[WebMethod]
public void Save(object file)
```

I get a 500 error with both of these, and the code never enters the backend function

Comment: WebMethod must be declared as static

Answer (score 0):

The signature that I have used in the past looks like this -

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{...
```

Please see the following reference -

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfilebase(v=vs.110).aspx